# How to get local date and time?

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I am using NSDate to get current time and date but it is giving date and time based on GMT.Please can anyone know how to get local time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547379/nsdate-is-not-returning-my-local-time-zone-default-time-zone-of-device

Answer (score 1):

NSDate has no knowledge of timezones.  It always stores dates as absolute moments in time, in GMT.

Use NSDateFormatter to get a local (or any other time zone) representation.

See the pertinent programming guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

Comment: How to get current locale?Can you please give some example?

Comment: If you use NSDateFormatter, it will use the current locale automatically by default. If you need to know the locale you can get it using [NSLocale currentLocale]

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding,I want to get local current time but I need in NSDate format only not in NSString so I cannot use NSDateFormatter also.and I cannot specify the Time Zone also because based on location it should automatically convert.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this? As I said, NSDate is expected to be in GMT. You are fighting the framework. This smells like a design flaw (such as conflating your model and view).

Comment: Because I want to insert the same time in database when the operation is performed not based on GMT.

Comment: What database takes NSDate natively - none that I know of?  Or do you really mean Core Data?  If you are inserting into a normal database you will need a string representation, which NSDateFormatter gets you.  Alternatively (I would say better for many situations), you could store the GMT/UTC date and, separately, the UTC offset.  Then add the two together in your SELECT statements.

Answer (score 1):

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:systemTimeZone];
```

set the timezone of the date using a date formatter with the above method. It will work. Convert the date to string, set the format and timezone and convert back to date.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I found this from another site

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate] autorelease];
```

Link for the website is [here](http://buildingmyworld.wordpress.com/2011/04/13/get-local-time-from-iphone-local-nsdate/)

Comment: But is this help when the difference is in "-"?