# Why is NSDateFormatter returning a date that is off by one hour?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I'm in PDT (pacific daylight time) which is -0700 hrs behind UTC.  I'm using `NSDateFormatter` to parse a time string, 4:00 PM, and then create a date:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSDate *aDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
aDate = [df dateFromString:@"4:00 PM"];
```

`aDate` returns as: 1970-01-02 00:00:00 +0000.  However, I'd expect it to return: 1970-01-01 23:00:00 +0000 since 4PM should be 23:00 UTC.

Checking the date formatter time zone returns the correct (PDT) time zone, ie: America/xxx (PDT) offset -25200 (Daylight)

Does anybody know what is going on here?  Thanks in advance for the help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without specifying the date, you'll be in PST, not PDT.  Try it again with:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"EEE, d LLL yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *aDate = [df dateFromString:@"Sat, 21 Apr 2012 04:00 PM"];
NSLog(@"date=%@", aDate);
```

Comment: The code above returns: 2012-04-21 19:00:00 +0000. 19:00:00 is 7pm which I can't explain how that is calculated.

Comment: 7 - 7 = 0.  Run it through this, where sourceDate = aDate;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547379/nsdate-is-not-returning-my-local-time-zone-default-time-zone-of-device.

Comment: danh I don't understand your comment.  7-7=0?

Comment: @JakeV - geez, I thought I understood it when I answered (1900 is 7pm, minus 7 is 12:00), but maybe that was a late night (PDT) brain-fart.  Now I'm confused, too.  Let me think about this and get back to you.

Comment: Changed the "HH" to "hh", since you're using a 12-hour clock.

Comment: @KenThomases is spot on.  Nice catch. +1. Will edit.  Ran it (like I should have to begin with) and it works as expected.