# NSDate object reciving fron NSString with different values

Tags: iphone, ios, nsdate

i like to fetch local device time and assign to string object .

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM , yyyy"];
self.dateSting=[[NSMutableString alloc]init];
self.dateSting = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@" ,[dateformatter stringFromDate:currentDate]];
```

output received = 6 March , 2013

convert `NSString` to `NSDate` object back code below

```
NSDateFormatter *uu=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[uu setDateFormat:@"d MMMM , yyyy"];

NSDate *yy=[uu dateFromString:self.dateSting];
```

output recived=2013-03-05 18:30:00 +0000
difference coming in days.

Comment: The second log was made to NSDate and first was on NSString, The NSDate will always show in GMT 00:00. You should accept the answer by @MicRO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
NSDate* currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"%@",currentDate);
NSDateFormatter *dateformatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateformatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM hh:mm:ss, yyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@",[dateformatter stringFromDate:currentDate]);

NSDate *yy=[dateformatter dateFromString:[dateformatter stringFromDate:currentDate]];
NSLog(@"%@",yy);

NSDateFormatter *uu=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[uu setDateFormat:@"d MMMM , yyyy"];

NSLog(@"%@",[uu stringFromDate:yy]);
```

The difference in date and time occurs due to the GMT offset. NSLogging NSDate give you time with the offset. The offset shows the value to be added or subtracted from date. In India its +5.30. Always make sure to keep the offset details as they may change the actual date if absent. Hope this helps.

Comment: always keep the general format of date with the time and its offset, when you need to show the date as formatted, use a formatter, shape it to a format as required and then show. If the offset gets clipped of, there may be inaccuracy in time and date due to the difference in time zone

Comment: i set look  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM hh:mm:ss, yyyy"];     NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
             [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"hh:mm a"];
             NSString *formattedDateString = [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:date];
            NSLog(@"yyy=%@",formattedDateString);
its giving answer in Am but it should be PM

Comment: It shows the correct value. When I used this code i got correct value. Please check. I am getting PM which is correct with respect to current time

Answer (score 4):

Well, the solution is fairly simple. `NSDate` always shows [GMT](http://wwp.greenwichmeantime.com/).
And from you profile, I can see that your present location is [INDIA](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=time+zone+of+INdia&aq=f&oq=time+zone+of+INdia&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.3530&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=5&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=oof-FrBxBj2E96JNiLQe4g&pq=time%20zone%20of%20india&cp=14&gs_id=3&xhr=t&q=time+zone+of+india&es_nrs=true&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=time+zone+of+Idia&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.bmk&fp=22e7cbac4256cbc1&biw=1022&bih=632) , where the local time zone is GMT +5.30hrs.

The current output you got is `2013-03-05 18:30:00 +0000` to which if you add 5.30hrs you will get `2013-03-06 00:00:00 +0000`. Please note that at the end of `NSDate` you can see something like `+0000`, this shows the timezone.

This is the reason/solution for your question and if you want to know how get it solved ,the [answer is here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7213629/1756131).

Hope everything is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

dateWithString:
Creates and returns an NSDate object with a date and time value specified by a given string in the international string representation format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM).

- (id)dateWithString:(NSString *)aString
  Parameters
  aString
  A string that specifies a date and time value in the international string representation format—YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM, where ±HHMM is a time zone offset in hours and minutes from GMT (for example, “2001-03-24 10:45:32 +0600”).
  You must specify all fields of the format string, including the time zone offset, which must have a plus or minus sign prefix.