# setting default time zone is not successfull

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsdate

i have used `setDefaultTimezone` to set the timezone and displayed the time and location in a `UITableview`. [image]

and i used below code to set default timezone

```
[cell.detailTextLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", evnt.location]];
[NSTimeZone setDefaultTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:evnt.location]];
[cell.textLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[NSDate date]]];
```

what i have to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547379/nsdate-is-not-returning-my-local-time-zone-default-time-zone-of-device

Comment: @Tendulkar got it now working... i have to check it again....

Comment: Thats ok . By pasting the same code I dont want to increase the load on Stackoverflow server . Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Use NSCalendar, and the setTimeZone method.

```
  NSDate *newDate;
  NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:~              NSTimeZoneCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];

  newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
  NSLog(@"newDate: %@", newDate);
  NSLog(@"newDate: %.0f", [newDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

newDate: 2011-09-09 15:02:09 +0000 
newDate: 337273330

```
  [dateComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Sydney"]];
  newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
  NSLog(@"newDate: %@", newDate);
  NSLog(@"newDate: %.0f", [newDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

newDate: 2011-09-09 00:52:03 +0000 
newTimeInterval: 337222930

```
 [dateComponents setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Europe/Paris"]];
 newDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];
 NSLog(@"newDate: %@", newDate);
 NSLog(@"newDate: %.0f", [newDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]);
```

newDate: 2011-09-09 08:52:03 +0000 
newTimeInterval: 337251730

Comment: my location time is exatcly 12:10 pm but returning 6:37 pm.

Answer (score 0):

`-[NSDate description]` always prints the date in UTC.

So try to do this:

```
NSDate *myDate = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
```

Plus check the below:

[NSDate is not returning my local Time zone /default time zone of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547379/nsdate-is-not-returning-my-local-time-zone-default-time-zone-of-device)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260787/setdefaulttimezone-not-working

[Convert UTC NSDate to local Timezone Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268509/convert-utc-nsdate-to-local-timezone-objective-c)