# Date object is showing date with minus 5:30hr when compare to current time.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

When i create an object for `NSDate` and put cursor on that object it was showing currect date like below[image]

and when am trying to log that object it was showing date with minus 5:30hr like below
[image]

and when I add offset to date and put cursor on that object it was showing date with plus 5:30hr like below

```
NSInteger offset = [[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone] secondsFromGMT];
```

[image]

and when am trying to log that object it was showing exact date like below

[image]

Why its happening like this? Is this problem with timezone?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your actual date is correct. Just NSLog show NSDate in +0000 GMT without you current GMT offset.

Answer (score 1):

NSDate always comes as a GMT. So you have to format the date as per your required timeZone.. You can set your device timeZOne or can use Calendar to set the timeZOne..

Answer (score 0):

NSDate is a "raw" date. That's why it is in GMT and your local and default time zone is GMT +5. It's up to the code to use NSDateFormatter to output the date to a value that makes sense for the user. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547379/nsdate-is-not-returning-my-local-time-zone-default-time-zone-of-device).

```
NSDate* sourceDate = [NSDate date];

NSTimeZone* sourceTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"];
NSTimeZone* destinationTimeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

NSInteger sourceGMTOffset = [sourceTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSInteger destinationGMTOffset = [destinationTimeZone secondsFromGMTForDate:sourceDate];
NSTimeInterval interval = destinationGMTOffset - sourceGMTOffset;

NSDate* destinationDate = [[[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:interval sinceDate:sourceDate]];
```

Answer (score 0):

> NSDate description return string representation in the international
>   format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS ±HHMM, where ±HHMM represents the time zone
>   offset in hours and minutes from GMT.

If you want  currentLocale, Use:

```
[date descriptionWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]]
```