# NSDateFormatter gives me back Greenwich time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter, localtime

I get the date and time with this void:

```
-(void)getDay
{

NSDate *choice = [NSDate date];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yy"];
year = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:choice] intValue];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM"];
month = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:choice] intValue];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
day = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:choice] intValue];


[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HH"];
hour = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

//   NSLog(@"hour: %d",hour);

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm"];
minute = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ss"];
second = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]] intValue];

}
```

if I see the log hour... it gives me the right hour in my local time, but when I put that value in another NSDate that I need to create the hour change and become the Greenwich time, here's the code I use:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS"];
   // NSLog(@"hour: %d",hour);
  //this log still gives me the right hour

    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

    self.myDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d",day,month,year,hour,minute,second]];
  NSLog(@"my date: %@",myDate);
```

This last log looks like this:

> 2013-08-31 05:14:12.905 myApp[25987:904] my date: 2013-08-31 15:14:00 +0000

my hour should be 5:14 but instead it is 15:14 that is Greenwich time...
Why is this happening and how can I get the local time and not the Greenwich one?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466744/getting-date-from-nsdate-date-off-by-a-few-hours, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547379/nsdate-is-not-returning-my-local-time-zone-default-time-zone-of-device.

Comment: Printing an `NSDate` in the console will always show GMT. If you set a breakpoint and look at it in your local variables, you'll see the date in the local timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code. The problem is that NSLog displays the date in GMT time. Try to put a breakpoint in the NSLog and you will see that self.myDate has the correct time whereas the NSLog displays the time in GMT.

I realized that in the formatter string you are using SS for the seconds. You have to use ss.