# Convert time to local time in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm having this issue where the correct time is passed but once it hits the `[formatter setDateFormat:date]` it comes out in a different time zone. Here is a snippet

```
NSDate* date = user.startDate;
NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLog(@"-------> (1) time is %@", date);
NSLog(@"-------> (2) time is %@", date);
[format setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
NSLog(@"-------> (3) time is %@", date);
NSLog(@"-------> (4) time is %@", [format stringFromDate:date]);
```

Here is the debugger output for the log messages

```
-------> (1) time is 2016-06-30 09:25:17 +0000
-------> (2) time is 2016-06-30 09:25:17 +0000
-------> (3) time is 2016-06-30 09:25:17 +0000
-------> (4) time is 2:25 AM
```

I'm expecting the output for `(4)` to be `time is 9:25 AM`

Comment: I removed code that's irrelevant to your question (but kept the duplicate lines in so that the references in the answers remain valid).

Comment: Note that (1), (2), (3) are just doing the exact samt thing. The date is immutable and the same instance, and you're not using a formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your time zone is apparently UTC-7000.

`NSLog` prints `NSDate` objects always in UTC, `NSDateFormatter` considers the current time zone. The printed dates are actually the same.

If you really need all dates in UTC, set the time zone of the formatter.

```
format.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
```

By the way: There are built-in methods to check if a date is in today or yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what is going on: the log of a date will always be GMT. (I don't think it makes sense for me to get into details as there is a great explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547607/4380483).) That means that log 1, 2 and 3 will be “wrong” (not in your timezone) and that should be expected.

If, for instance, you want to log the string as GMT, you can change the property `timeZone` of your date formatter.

Dealing with dates can be extremely hard. Please take the time to read if not all, some important parts of [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html) document (fundamentals/basics).